# How can proceed further

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, differential

**Question**
The given partial differential equation is $$px+qy+pq=xz$$
**My approach**
Where $p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $q= \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

By using *charpit* method
$$ \frac{dx}{F_p}=\frac{dy}{F_q}=\frac{dz}{pF_p+qF_q} =\frac{-dp}{F_x+pF_z}=\frac{-dq}{F_y+qF_z} $$
Putting the values

> > $$\frac{dx}{x+q}=\frac{dy}{xy+p}=\frac{dz}{px+qxy+2pq}=\frac{-dp}{p+qy-z-px}=\frac{-dq}{qx-qx}$$
> >     From the last fraction of $dq$ we get
> >     $q=a$, where $a$ is *arbitary* constant.

Substituting the value of $q$ in given *PDE* we get $p$ as $$p= \frac{x(z-ay)}{x+a}$$
Further the solution of the differential equation be $dz=pdx+qdy$.

From above we get $$dz= \left[\frac{x(z-ay)}{x+a} \right]dx + ady $$
**My question**

**1)** How can i integrate the above formed equation, as i am unable to do so.

**2)** Is there any chance of converting above given equation into standard **clairaut's** form ?

Any subtle hint is highly appreciated 
Thankyou

Comment: I don't agree with your Charpit's equations : $$\frac{dx}{x+q}=\frac{dy}{xy+p}=\frac{dz}{px+qxy+2pq}=\frac{-dp}{p+qy-z-px}=\frac{-dq}{qx-qx}$$ I suspect several typos. And what are the boundary conditions ?

Comment: The boundry conditions are not given.

Comment: The typo is in the writting of the PDE. See my answer.

Comment: @Vedant Chourey I see you have never validated any of the answers that have been provided to you. Please do it: for example here, you should check the good answer of JJacquelin. This is helpful for an efficient use of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PDE is 
$$px+qy+pq=xz\:,$$
the Charpit's equations are :
$$\frac{dx}{x+q}=\frac{dy}{y+p}=\frac{dz}{px+qy+2pq}=\frac{-dp}{p-z-px}=\frac{-dq}{q-qx}$$
This is not what you wrote.

Then $z=ay+be^x(x+a)^{-a}$ is not solution of the above PDE.
$$ $$

If the Charpit's equations are :
$$\frac{dx}{x+q}=\frac{dy}{xy+p}=\frac{dz}{px+qxy+2pq}=\frac{-dp}{p+qy-z-px}=\frac{-dq}{qx-qx}$$
The PDE is :
$$px+qxy+pq=xz$$
This is not the PDE written in your question.

$$\boxed{z=ay+be^x(x+a)^{-a}\quad\text{is solution of}\quad px+qxy+pq=xz}$$

Comment: Got it i have a missing term $ay$, thank you for the correction.

Comment: Don't mention it. Also you should add the $x$ missing in the original equation of the PDE.

Answer (score 0):

From the last equation formed in question
$$dz = \left[\frac{x(z-ay)}{x+a}\right]dx + ady $$
$$\frac{dz}{z-ay}= \frac{x dx}{x+a} + \frac{a dy}{z-ay} $$
And 
$$\frac{dz-ady}{z-ay} = \frac{x+a}{x+a} + \frac{a}{x+a} $$
 Integrating the  above equation
$$ log_e(z-ay) = x -alog_e(x+a) + log_e{b}$$
Where $log_e{b}$ is arbitrary constant

$$ log_e(z-ay) = x+ log_e(x+a)^{-a} +log_e{b} $$
And the final answer be
$$z = be^{x}(x+a)^{-a} +ay$$

**edit** :- added the missing term $ay$ in Right hand side.
As suggested by *JJacquelin*

Comment: Did you put your result $z = ay+be^{x}(x+a)^{-a}$ into the PDE $px+qy+pq=xz$ ? It seems not satisfying.

Comment: Didn't try that but the answer matches form the book

Comment: See my answer...